# Drupal 6.29 Jquery Update et. don't work

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-6

Those of you with Drupal sites may know: 6.29 came out with an EARLIER version of jQuery. I was running jQuery Update and some dependencies.
Suddenly jQuery update just doesn't work. Matter of fact: common method of using _preprocess_page() does not either. Currently have to run the site without consolidating scripts and did a string replace with a file path for /misc/jquery.js
Tried this in template.php in my theme to no avail too:

```
function my_theme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (arg(0) != 'admin' || !(arg(1) == 'add' && arg(2) == 'edit') || arg(0) != 'panels' || arg(0) != 'ctools') {
    $scripts = drupal_add_js();
    $new_jquery = array(
      drupal_get_path('theme', 'my_theme') . '/js/jq-1.7.2.min.js' => $scripts['core']['misc/jquery.js']);
    $scripts['core'] = array_merge($new_jquery, $scripts['core']);
    unset($scripts['core']['misc/jquery.js']);
    $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js('header', $scripts);
  }
}
```

Hope someone can shine some light. This is a big problem, slowing down cached pages by a couple seconds. Can't imagine someone more knowledgeable wouldn't know, but nothing on Google.

Answer (score 0):

OK that's embarrassing! I noticed when I was editing the code block above that I misspelled the variable. I had `$variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js('header', $scripts);`
Boy do I feel sheepish.